# Write data to Excel file

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I have tried these below code which copies Excel read file data to Excel write data file, but I want web elements to Excel write data file. Want each `tr` and `td` data to Excel file using Selenium Java. In the same class reading from excel file and want to write web elements data to Excel file.

````
public class NewTest {
    public static String driverPath = "D:/Testing/Drivers/";
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        System.out.println("launching chrome browser");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath+"chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("anyurl");
        WebElement id = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='txt_username']"));
        id.sendKeys("anyusername");
        WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='txt_password']"));
        pass.sendKeys("anypass");
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtCaptcha")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,100);
        new WebDriverWait(driver,100).until(ExpectedConditions.urlToBe("anyurl"));
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Exit")).click();
        driver.get("anyurl");
                FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("D:\\Test.xls"); //or xlsx
                XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
                Cell cell = row.getCell(0);    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id=\'aspnetForm\']/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/input")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id=\'aspnetForm\']/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/input")).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id=\'aspnetForm\']/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/input[2]")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id=\'aspnetForm\']/div[3]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/input[2]")).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id=\'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btn_submit\']")).click();
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*tr[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tr_data']/td/div/table/tbody"));
                List<WebElement> tbdy = element.findElements(By.tagName("tbody"));
                List<WebElement> tr = tbdy.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
            try {
                    String filename = "D:\\Test.xls";
                    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
                    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("FirstSheet");
                    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();//Create style
                    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
                     }
                    for (int i = 0; i < tr.size(); i++) {
                        HSSFRow row2 = sheet.createRow(i+1);
                        List<WebElement> td = tr.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
                        for (int j = 0; j < td.size(); j++) {
                            td.get(j).getText();
                        row2.createCell(j).setCellValue(td.get(j).getText());
                        }
                    }
                    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                    workbook.write(fileOut);
                    fileOut.close();
                    System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");
}
     }```
````

Comment: You will need to clean up the question a bit before anyone can help you with this. It is unclear what you are trying to say. Please do your best to use complete thoughts and sentences. Technical questions are hard to answer and it becomes impossible to answer when we can't form a proper understanding of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you are doing, but here is a generic example that should help get you going in the right direction.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\\Utility\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://www.ultimatetennisstatistics.com/playerProfile?playerId=4742")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='playerPills']//a[@class='dropdown-toggle'][normalize-space()='Statistics']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']//a[@id='statisticsPill'][normalize-space()='Statistics']"))).click()
statistics_items = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table table-condensed table-hover table-striped']//tbody//tr/td")))
statistics_value = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table table-condensed table-hover table-striped']//tbody//tr//following::th[1]")))
for item, value in zip(statistics_items, statistics_value):
    print('{} {}'.format(item.text, value.text))
```

Result:

```
Ace % 4.0%
Double Fault % 2.1%
1st Serve % 68.7%
1st Serve Won % 71.8%
2nd Serve Won % 57.3%
Break Points Saved % 66.3%
Service Points Won % 67.2%
Service Games Won % 85.6%
```

Now, instead of printing the results, send everything to a dataframe and save the dataframe to Excel.

```
df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```